# Dependency errors during OpenERP installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo

Im trying to install OpenERP v7 on ubuntu and when I try to install the dependencies I get this error:

```
E: Package 'python-pychart' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-pydot' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-vobject' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-CherryPy3
E: Package 'python-pybabel' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-matplotlib' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-hippocanvas
E: Package 'python-pydot' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-webdav' has no installation candidate
```

I have been searching on google on how to solve it but nothing has helped so far. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

hi this is a command for all dependencies for openerp 7 in ubuntu 12.04 or later:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-gdata \
python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid \
python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing \
python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject \
python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
```

Comment: hi! I was using the above command and even then getting the errors. However I solved it by upgrading Ubuntu. Thanks anyway